# Passing struct from ObjC to Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to use a struct from ObjC to Swift doesn't seem to be that easy. I end up getting a Unsafe pointer that I don't know if I can cast reliably.

Here is the code:

```
//
// In OBJC land
//

// Type declared as a struct

typedef struct node {
    int children_count;
} node_t;

// Super class has a property

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) node_t *node;


//
// In SWIFT land
//

// Derived class tries to set the property inside the C struct


let n: UnsafeMutablePointer<node_t> = super.node // As swift compiler sees it
n.children_count = 0    // ERR!!!
```

Do I really need to apply unsafeBitcast here or is there a simpler/safer and more elegant way to convert what seems to be a frequent scenario?

**UPDATE:**

I tried using *memory* to access the elements of the struct and I am getting a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

```
var node: node_t = self.node.memory
node.children_count = 42
```

**UPDATE CONT'D & FINALE**

I got it to work. Thanks to @matt's patience for making sure I groked 'memory' access completely. The other trick is to realize the assignment in one continuous statement like this:

```
    var node: UnsafeMutablePointer<node_t> = self.node
    node.memory.children_count = 42
```

If I do the following, the change doesn't get committed passed the function call:

```
var node: node_t = self.node.memory
node.children_count = 42
```

Comment: "If I do the following, the change doesn't get committed passed the function call" Ah, very good point; yes, because in Swift the assignment of the struct to `node` causes that struct to be copied.

Comment: Done. Slow Sunday. Thanks @matt

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it - I really was prepared to send you a demo project if you needed it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that this is *not* a "frequent scenario". In fact, this is a very odd thing to do:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) node_t *node;
```

This thing (`node_t`) is a C struct. So why do you want a *pointer* to it? Perhaps you have no choice about this, but far and away the usual thing is simply to have the struct itself *as* a property:

```
@property (readonly) node_t *node;
```

In that way, the property arrives as a Swift struct called `node_t`, and if you have a `var` reference to it (not a `let` as you've written it), you can assign into its `children_count` directly, as you would expect.

If you insist on having a pointer, then you will have to dereference the pointer, won't you? You are not doing that. To do so, take the pointer's `memory`:

```
n.memory.children_count = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as you guessed, I don't have any choice but to use what's in there. The code is inherited from a objectiveC framework that I can't modify. I need  a way to bridge the struct somehow. I hope there is a way.

Comment: See my revised answer. - Yes, I did guess that. :)

Comment: Also, are you sure you need `super`? If we are the subclass, we inherit this instance variable and `self` should work.

Comment: I merely used 'super' to examplify my use case (just to show that I am indeed inheriting it.) Terrible code that I wouldn't check in. Thanks for code reviewing with an eagle eye though.

Comment: So how about that little `memory` trick - is that working? (Of course it assumes that this property has been correctly initialized - i.e. the pointer is in fact pointing at something - but that is not a part of the question. If the pointer is _not_ pointing at the desired struct, you would obviously crash.)

Comment: The 'memory' trick would work. Unfortunately, there are a few fields in front of the 'children_count' that makes it very unpredictable what would be the offset for that one. I think I am going to stick with that method in the '.m' bridge file.

Comment: No, I don't see that. If `n` is `super.node` as in your code (or `self.node`), then it is a pointer to a struct. That is what a `UnsafeMutablePointer<node_t>` is. So `n.memory` _is the struct_. This is exactly the same as dereferencing a pointer in Objective-C. `memory` is _how_ you dereference a pointer in Swift. There are no offsets involved. You now have the struct as a Swift struct and can assign into its properties. Try it.

Comment: Well, I already explained that in my previous comment. This is a pointer. If it hasn't already been set to point to an actual struct, you will obviously crash. And you cannot set it yourself because it is read only. But that's not my affair. I can send you a test project in which I am in charge of the Objective-C side and the Swift side, and it works perfectly, I assure you.